# Excel: If functions

Tags: excel, data-analysis, iif-function

I would like to work out the below but I couldn't figure it out yet:

For a specific date, I would like to know what is the average price of the data collected starting from 2 minutes after Time (T) 
-i.e Looking for the date 01/01/2018  08:30 the average price of the money transfered 2 minutes after 08:30 taking into consideration that my data includes all days of the quarter.

Could anyone help me on this?

Comment: Please always provide your code - other current efforts at solving the question. **We're here to help you with your code, not to do the coding for you!**

Comment: As a hint, have a look at countif()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would recommend to add column B with formula "=minute(A1)" (in A1 you have the date in date format), then simple averageifs function will help you: =averageifs(C1:C2;B1:B2;">=30";B1:B2;"<=32").